# New to c#, not understanding online compiler

Tags: c#

so I wrote some C# code and I am trying to test it incrementally, do to something that would take a while to explain, but bottom line, I'm new to c# and not understanding the online compiler error messages. Here is the error message I get when I try and compile, but the strings look good to me.

```html
string solutionSet = "white|black|beige|pink|green|blue|red|yellow|orange|cyan|purple|brown";
            string[] solutionSetArray = new string[12];
            string ret = "";
            string delimeter = "|";
            int tempPos = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            int successFlag = 0;
            int patternLength = 5;
            for (int index = 0; index < solutionSet.Length; index++)
            {
                if (solutionSet[index] == delimeter)
                {
                    solutionSetArray[counter] = solutionSet.Substring(tempPos, index);
                    tempPos = index + 1;
                    counter++;
                }
                if (solutionSet.Length - index == 1)
                {
                    solutionSetArray[solutionSetArray.Length-1] = solutionSet.Substring(tempPos, solutionSet.Length);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int randIndex = rnd.Next(solutionSetArray.Length);
                if (i != patternLength - 1)
                {
                    ret += solutionSetArray[randIndex] + "|";
                    successFlag++;
                }
                else
                {
                    ret += solutionSetArray[randIndex];
                }

            }
            if (successFlag == patternLength - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ret);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            }
```

Comment: Post some code here instead of a picture

Comment: postedddddddddd

Comment: `string[] solutionSetArray = solutionSet.Split('|');` maybe?? Or `char` delimeter = '|';`

Comment: I vote for `char delimeter = '|';` like @JohnnyMopp says

Comment: still issues, it says..**main.cs(1,18): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `myclass', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', or `struct'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

exit status 1**

Comment: You must wrap your code in a method in a class. An the method must be called Main to be the entry point.

Answer (score 1):

The error (which, according to the message, is on line 1, column 11) is being caused by your very first line of code, which begins `string`.

I can't tell the context from  just your post, but my guess is that you are declaring `solutionSet` in a block that is not inside of a class or function.  You should enclose your code in a class or method, e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        string solutionSet = "white|black|beige|pink|green|blue|red|yellow|orange|cyan|purple|brown";
        //Rest of code goes here
    }
}
```

By the way, if you're trying to convert `solutionSet` to an array, you can just write

```
var solutionSetArray = solutionSet.Split("|");
```

Comment: in c# are all primitives handled using just var? can you not declare the actual type of object?

Comment: you can use actual type of object. `var` is just a common one where c# finds the type what the right hand side is returning and creates it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is

```
 solutionSetArray[counter] = solutionSet.Substring(tempPos, index);
```

after 6 iterations `tempPos=34` and `index=37` which is running out of bounds of solutionSet. I would suggest to use  `var solutionSetArray = solutionSet.Split("|");` and also use LinqPad which can be easy for you to debug if possible,.

Comment: Can anyone show me where you guys are compiling? This is the problem I can't run my code anywhere :/ I'm having to write and test and another language

Comment: We use VisualStudio